# How to add slide in card slider bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I found a tutorial to make card slider in [codepen](https://codepen.io/JuniVersal/pen/zNyMRd) but this tutorial only support 5 slide, and i need 10 slide. How to modify it?

I think  this is the line to modify.

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------
    2.0 Cards
    --------------------------------------------------------------*/
    .slider__item {
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: 
        cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
            transition-timing-function: 
         cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
    }

    #slide-1:checked ~ .slider__holder .slider__item--1 {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      transform: translate(0) scale(1);
    }

    #slide-2:checked ~ .slider__holder .slider__item--1 {
      z-index: 1;
      transform: translateX(-100px) scale(0.85);
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      #slide-2:checked ~ .slider__holder .slider__item--1 {
        opacity: 0.6;
      }
    }
    #slide-3:checked ~ .slider__holder .slider__item--1 {
      z-index: 0;
      transform: translateX(-210px) scale(0.65);
    }

    @media (max-width: 900px) {
      #slide-3:checked ~ .slider__holder .slider__item--1 {
        transform: translateX(-170px) scale(0.65);
      }
    }
... etc
```

but it is  difficult to modify it.
[Link](https://codepen.io/JuniVersal/pen/zNyMRd) to code pen. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: It's supports you can add slides howmany you want but you need to modify css . Because slides have transform property on clicking

Comment: i know i must modify css, but i difficulty to modify it, like my question

Comment: my question is, how to modify css can support 10 slide?

Comment: Cloudflare is currently offline & consequently Codepen too _ so the links to the tutorial aren't working for the moment